# ad-hoc distribution itunes sync error

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning

So I have been at this for a while and I can't find anything that helps. When I try to install my ipa onto the device through iTunes I get the app was unable to sync error. I have considered the following:

My app is using a distribution profile. I have the device registered in that distribution profile.

I have the placed the distribution profile on the device by dragging it into iTunes.

The entitlements plist matches that in the provisioning distribution profile.

The app runs up until the point of "process cannot attach" when I run it in Xcode which is to be expected as get-task-allow is set to false.

I am not sure what I could be missing here, any ideas?

Comment: Before you drag and drop check if that ipa file is already tre. This happens often if not go and do hard reset and it will work.

Comment: I tried erasing all of the provisioning profiles on the device, that didn't help. I tried a hard reset also, still get the same error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an ad-hoc profile to include your test devices UDIDs in that profile.  Drag and drop that profile into the iTunes.

Comment: Turns out I had the wrong one selected on the list when signing the ipa file. Rigourous detail checking on all of your steps taken seems to be the best solution to these provisioning shtuffs